# Declare Name/Variable with Docker Compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Currently I am experimenting with Docker Compose but I want to declare a variable or something and some parts of my code and my folder name get changed when I run `docker-compose run ...`

Is that even possible with Docker?

I want to generate a Django-Template and change some parts in the "INSTALLED_APPS" section.

I cannot find something in the web or on stackoverflow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Environment variables in docker-composel.yml in your use case

Refer here for more details : https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/